# MCCordovaPlugin, getting Push Notifications only when contactKey is set to my phone number?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, cordova, pushtopic, push

I don't remember if my phone number is somehow tied to sending push notifications or not.

At this point, I am always able to successfully send and receive outbound push notifications if i setContactKey to my phone number. If I setContactKey to any other GUID or random non-empty, non-null value, I do not receive push notification events.

What could be amiss?
Where can I change something so that contactKey can be anything else other than my phone number?
At this point, outbound push notifications to all users is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The only way `Contact Key` can affect your outbound push messages is during list creation.  You need to make sure your audience list contains all the devices/contacts for which you wish to send a push message.  Additionally, take note of the "refresh on send" option and apply to your list as appropriate.